# React inline style not working with props

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, interpolation

I am trying to control the attributes left and right with props but keep coming up with an error

> "Syntax error: this is a reserved word"

I've tried several different methods (and looked at various examples on StackO) to solve my answer and keep coming up with error.  I've shortened my code to get to the meat and potatoes here.

I have this in my App.js, it works with Pulse.js until I try to pass props

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="App">
     <Nav />
     <Content />
     <Pulse top="-124" left="300" />
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And here is the code from Pulse.js

```
class Pulse extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Star style={{top: {this.props.top} + 'em'}}></Star>
    );
  }
}

export default Pulse;
```

when I enter "this.props.top" as my style, I get my error.  I've tried various methods to fix this and continue coming up with errors.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<Star style={{top: {this.props.top} + 'em'}}></Star>
```

Remove the syntactically invalid wrapping `{}` around `this.props.top`

```
<Star style={{top: this.props.top + 'em'}}></Star>
```

A bit more explanation:

JSX is a "DSL", a domain specific language. It's not Javascript. In JSX, you can put vanilla Javascript expressions inside of curly braces in some places, like

```
<Star style={...vanilla javascript expression...} />
```

Once you're inside the curly braces, there's no need for additional curly braces to read variables. You can reference `this.props.top` without wrapping it in more curly braces.

When you use this syntax: `{this.props.top}` the compiler gets confused, thinking you're trying to build a javascript object like `{a: 'b'}` but instead of `a`, you're trying to use the word `this`, which is a reserved word in Javascript. The compiler thinks you're trying to do something like `{this: this}` which is invalid, because the bare word `this` is a reserved word.

Comment: Andy Ray, if it were possible to hug you right now, I would.  I've been banging my head against the wall all day on this.  THANK YOU

Comment: one other question, I tried also putting in the prop "left" too and it's not working, I assume this is incorrect syntax: 

`<Star style={{top: this.props.top + 'px;'}}  {{left: this.props.left + 'px;'}}></Star>`

Comment: Yup, again you're just in regular Javascript expression land now. You can't put two javascript objects side by side `var objs = {a: b} {c: d};` You can combine them here: `{{top: this.props.top + 'px;', left: this.props.left + 'px;'}}`. It's a little confusing but `style={{}}` with double curly braces just means a javascript object `{...}` inside of the JSX wrapping `style={ }`

Comment: thank you so much, very much appreciated.  I'm a designer and just now making it into React, so a lot of my js gets mixed up.

Comment: Good for you for diving in!